# How do I center text or image on fixed size of div using css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `div` with fixed height & width. In the div have image with **unknown** height & width. How do I center the image.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/huhu/UyBNh/

I want the output to be like https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x9qH.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#center {
    display:table-cell; 
    width:400px; 
    height:400px; 
    border:1px solid #444; 
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    text-align:center}
```

This sets your div to be treated like a table cell, which has excellent support for centering.  You don't need any CSS for the image.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use CSS. You can style it inline (if you are outputting from the DB sometimes this is the best way). Or assign it to a class. Either way:

```
background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW66h.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VTgWg/1/

Here's a demo showing different size images: http://jsfiddle.net/r2wm2/1/

I've seen cases like this where you want to link the image. Here's an example of exchanging the div for an `<a>` tag: http://jsfiddle.net/zSuzm/1/

Comment: +1 I like this one, but I want it without inline style if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This css works on your example:

```
#center {width:400px; height:400px; border:1px solid #444; margin:auto; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
#center img { margin:auto; display:block;}
```

Comment: What a different between `margin:auto` I've set to the image.

Comment: I didn't look at your example, sorry about that.  Try this quick tutorial: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to update the #center img section:

```
#center img {
    position: relative;
    left: 148px;
    top: 148px;
}
```

The center of the container would be 200px. Offsetting the image by 52px puts the center of the image on the center of the container.

Comment: yeah working for current image. if i replace the image with different size it back to my question.

Comment: Oh, heh...must've slipped into "literal mode" there and answered the case for an image without unknown height & width. Sorry bout that. You'll need a script, but the approach is the same: get the image size and then position it to 200 - (imageWidth / 2) and 200 - imageHeight / 2)

Comment: @yjoseph, boy, is my face red! I just kind of skipped on past the simple, clean solution, didn't I? Nice work!